# Datediff fuction in Access produce answer of 1 instead of 0 for same day

Tags: ms-access, datediff, date-difference

I am trying to get a total number of days hired using the DateDiff function is access.

I currently use:

```
=DateDiff("d",[hired_from],[hired_to])
```

To get the difference between two dates, however if the two dates selected are the same it will produce an output of 0, I would like it to produce an output of 1 when the two dates selected are the same, thanks.

Comment: please post complete code

Comment: This is for a textbox using the expression builder.

Comment: hired_from and hired_to and short date data types.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense as the difference between two identical values always will be zero.

So you probably mean:

```
=DateDiff("d",DateAdd("d",-1,[hired_from]),[hired_to])
```

or just add one to the count:

```
=DateDiff("d",[hired_from],[hired_to])+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making this work by using an if statement as shown:

```
==IIf(DateDiff("d",[hired_from],[hired_to])=0,1,DateDiff("d",[hired_from],[hired_to]))
```

Answer (score -1):

to get the difference of two dates (which is only a format for an integer value), you have only to subtract the two dates and make sure that the result format is an integer.

```
Variable = [hired_to]-[hired_from]
```

Comment: Well, but it doesn't address the question.

Comment: yes, but datediff is the wrong way, it should be allowed to show a better way, if somebody goes in a wrong direction, without beeing voted down, nice of you